# org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed. Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to send mail while authenticate the user but I am getting this error message.

`EmailService` class:

```java
@Service
public class EmailService {

    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private final MailConfigurationProperties mailConfigurationProperties;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);

    public EmailService( JavaMailSender mailSender, MailConfigurationProperties mailConfigurationProperties) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.mailConfigurationProperties = mailConfigurationProperties;
    }

    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String content) {
        logger.info("Sending email from [{}] to [{}] with subject [{}].",
                mailConfigurationProperties.getUsername(), to, subject);

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "utf-8");
        try {
            helper.setText(content, true);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setFrom(mailConfigurationProperties.getUsername());
            mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            logger.info("Successfully sent mail to: " + to);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to send email", e);
        }

    }
}
```

and here is where I am trying to send email from:

```java
@PostMapping("/signup")
public String signup(@RequestParam String email,
                        @RequestParam String fullname,
                        @RequestParam String username,
                        @RequestParam String password){

    User user = userService.saveUser(email, fullname, username, password);
    String random=userService.generateRandomString(16);
    userService.setVerificationCode(user, random);
    emailService.sendEmail(email, "timestamps app", random);

    return "redirect:/verify_email";
}
```

the **`application.yml`** file

```yaml
mail:
  host: smtp.gmail.com
  port: 587
  username: smth@gmail.com
  password: *********
  smtpAuth: true
  starttlsEnabled: true
```

Following exception I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed. Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `JavaMailSender` is not configured correctly from your `application.yaml`.

So the following properties

```
mail: 
  host: smtp.gmail.com 
  port: 587 
  username: smth@gmail.com 
  password: ********* 
  smtpAuth: true 
  starttlsEnabled: true
```

Are not considered when spring registers the bean `javaMailSender`.

Proof of this is your stacktrace

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
> failed. Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;

So your investigation should be why your relevant properties inside `application.yaml` are not considered for registration of `javaMailSender` from `spring`

Probably this happens because you might not have your properties inside a `spring` property like

```
spring 
    mail: 
      host: smtp.gmail.com 
      port: 587 
      username: smth@gmail.com 
      password: ********* 
      smtpAuth: true 
      starttlsEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found what has been causing this error. I didn't know that you need separate app password that you need to use for your application. With that generated password now its working.